# Create records in multiple tables using one entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to JPA and trying to build a simple REST API as a pet project to manage quiz questions. I'm trying to create a quiz question that has properties in multiple tables.

I have two entities and their corresponding SQL tables: QuizQuestion and Difficulty.

```
@Entity
public class QuizQuestion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    private int difficultyLevel;
}

@Entity
public class Difficulty {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private QuizQuestion quizQuestion;

    private int level;
    private int asked;
    private int correctlyAnswered;
}
```

I have an endpoint that creates a record in both tables. It first adds a new record in the QuizQuestion table, then adds a new record in the Difficulty table with the given difficultyLevel + some additional properties (asked, correctlyAnswered) set to 0 by default.

This is the function called by the endpoint:

```
 @Transactional
    public QuizQuestionDto createQuestion(QuizQuestion question) {
        // Save the question first to generate an ID
        QuizQuestion savedQuestion = quizQuestionRepository.save(question);

        // Create a new Difficulty instance
        Difficulty difficulty = new Difficulty();
        difficulty.setQuizQuestion(savedQuestion);
        difficulty.setLevel(question.getDifficultyLevel());
        difficulty.setAsked(0);
        difficulty.setCorrectlyAnswered(0);
        difficultyRepository.save(difficulty);
```

And this is my request payload:
{
"question": "Sample question",
"answer1": "Sample answer",
"difficultyLevel": 2
}

It works, and creates both records. However when I try to get a QuizQuestion using another endpoint, difficultyLevel is always returned as 0.

I suppose I'm not using the correct way to create such records as there is no connection between the two entities.
Maybe I should build a OneToOne mapping between QuizQuestion and Difficulty? I've tried doing that by having a "Difficulty" property in the QuizQuestion entity instead of "difficultyLevel", but then I had to provide a difficulty object in my request with all its properties.

{
"question": "Sample question",
"answer1": "Sample answer",
"difficulty": {
"difficultyLevel": 2,
"asked": 0,
"correctlyAnswered": 0
}
}

I'd like to avoid that if possible, but not sure if there is a better way.

Can you suggest what is the best way to handle such situations?

Comment: This code shows Question having a 'difficultyLevel' int property, is this what you are referring to? You never set it, so it will always be null. Are you looking to fetch the associated (if this is a strict OneToOne) Difficulty.level? If so, you'll have to tell JPA how to populate that when reading it in from the database. I'd suggest you just add a bidirectional relationship as you've seem to have tried to do with the displayed JSON

Answer (score 0):

As you've seem to have already tried, there is already a relationship from QuizQuestion to Difficulty that you just didn't map that you could leverage to get at the difficulty.level value:

```
@Entity
public class QuizQuestion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "quizQuestion")
    private Difficulty difficulty;
}
```

As this is mapped by the Difficulty.quizQuestion mapping, it is still only set from changes you make to the Difficulty instance. Just be careful with cascade options unless you are sure they are what you want on the mapping.

If you don't want to serialize the full difficulty instance over in the JSON for QuizQuestion, don't. JSON annotations can easily be customized, and added to a 'getDifficultyLevel' property:

```
@Entity
public class QuizQuestion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "quizQuestion")
    private Difficulty difficulty;

    @JsonProperty("difficultyLevel")
    Integer getDifficultyLevel() {
      return (null==difficulty)? null: difficulty.getLevel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get the difficultyLevel of an existing question with this.

But how can I create a new question with a given difficultyLevel?

This payload does not seem to be working: { "question": "Sample question", "answer1": "Sample answer", "difficultyLevel": 2 }

The problem is that I try to create a Difficulty object in my 'createQuestion' service function, but the 'getDifficultyLevel' call reads the Difficulty object which does not exist at that point.

Comment: POST vs PUT are going to require different solutions. You'll likely want to keep a JPA transient 'difficultyLevel' int in your entity and let JSON set it. On create, you'll need to create a new DifficultyLevel instance from that value. On Put/modify of the question, you'll need to modify the existing entity or just not allow changing the difficulty level through the question.